# Automatically converting function

Tags: kotlin

If I have the following code:

```
fun main() {
   println(Example("test", 1))
}

class Example(private val text: String, private val num: Int) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "String: $text $num"
    }
}
```

and it works.

Is there any way to do this for types different from string?

Example:

```
class Example {
    
    fun toList(): List {
        //Convert to list...
    }
}
```

```
thisFunctionRequireList(Example2())
```

Comment: Are you sure `thisFunctionRequireString(Example1())` works? Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: @Sweeper [Here is an example.](https://pl.kotl.in/ia_8L5I18)

Comment: Ah I see where your misunderstanding is. Please [edit] that code into your question, and I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will first explain how

```
println(Example1())
```

works, and from there, create something similar.

First, note that `println` has [many overloads](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/println.html). This `println` call does not call the `println(String)` overload. It calls the `println(Any?)` overload.

The `println(Any?)` overload is implemented to transform the `Any` parameter into a `String` using `toString`, and then calls the `println(String)` overload using that string. [Here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/f3385fbdcb8b9dc29661a8a4973c855cdcf73767/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/io/Console.kt#L24) is the Kotlin/Native implementation:

```
public actual fun println(message: Any?) {
    println(message.toString())
}
```

Note that it is able to do this, only because `Any?`, and by extension `Any`, declares the `toString` method. This allows it to convert any value you pass, to a `String`. At runtime, this gets dispatched to the `toString` override that you declared in `Example1`.

Therefore, it is not because you overrode `toString`, that you were able to call `println` with `Example`. It is because

- `println` has an overload that takes `Any`, allowing you to pass anything into it
- `Any` also declares a `toString` that you can override, which `println(Any)` also uses in its implementation

`Any` does not declare a `toList` method, so we can't use `Any` if we want to do the same for `List`.

We can declare a new interface for types that can be converted to lists:

```
interface ConvertibleToList<T> {
    fun toList(): List<T>
}
```

This is *like* an `Any`, but only for types that implement it. `Example2` can then implement the interface:

```
class Example2: ConvertibleToList<String> {
    
    override fun toList(): List<String> {
        //Convert to list...
    }
}
```

Now suppose there is an existing function that takes a `List<String>`:

```
fun doThingsToStrings(strings: List<String>) { ... }
```

You can add a new overload of this, with the parameter type being `ConvertibleToList<T>`:

```
fun doThingsToStrings(strings: ConvertibleToList<String>) = doThingsToStrings(strings.toList())
```

`doThingsToStrings` becomes just like `println`, with one overload taking the "exact" type (`List<String>`), and another overload taking types that can be converted to the "exact" type (`ConvertibleToList<String>`).

Now you can call `doThingsToStrings` with `Example2()`!